# VBA On Error GoTo not working

Tags: html, vba, excel, web-scraping

I'm looking at a specific div tag and if there's no innerText, I want to skip it and go to NextLink3. I think when there is no innerText however, I just get a run-time error: subscript out of range at `test = arr(LBound(arr))`, and I'm not sure how to deal with that. I thought "On Error GoTo" would see if the next line produces an error, and if it does, go somewhere else, but my following code doesn't do that and I still get the subscript error.

HTML code:

```
<div style="width: 555px; -ms-overflow-x: auto; -ms-overflow-y: hidden;">
 <a href="/kegg-bin/ddi_list?drug=D00550">
  <img name="DDI" align="middle" onmouseover="btn(this,'DDIbh')" onmouseout="btn(this,'DDIb')" onmousedown="btn(this,'DDIbd')" onmouseup="btn(this,'DDIb')" ontouchstart="btn(this,'DDIbd')" ontouchend="btn(this,'DDIb')" alt="Drug interaction" src="/Fig/bget/button_DDIb.gif" border="0">
 </a>
</div>
```

My VBA code:

```
Dim ele As Object, test As String
Set ele = html.querySelectorAll(".td50 div")(3)
    If Not ele Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo NextLink3
        arr = Split(ele.innerText, Chr$(10))
        On Error GoTo NextLink3
        test = arr(LBound(arr))
        If InStr(arr(LBound(arr)), "[HSA") = 0 Or InStr(arr(LBound(arr)), " [KO") = 0 Then GoTo NextLink3
        For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
            Debug.Print Split(arr(i), "[")(0)
        Next i
        GoTo NextLink
    End If

NextLink3: 
...
```

Comment: you don't need to continue repeating the on error. Can you share the full link that this is failing with? The code above.

Comment: @QHarr no matter where/how many I put it never skips the runtime error at test = arr(LBound(arr))

Comment: Yes - but in this particular case I want to go to NextLink3 because I was searching in this div tag and didn't find any innerText

Comment: Instead of using so many goto's, how about testing the array with `If IsArray(arr) Then...`

Comment: Do you have "Break on All Errors" enabled?

Comment: @PeterT I just tried that but it still enters the If statement, although I don't think there is anything in arr

Comment: @Comintern No i don't

Comment: I know that there are a lot of other problems with the code being discussed, but just taking the problem at face value you could probably avoid this error with `If len(ele.inntertext) > 0 then` so that you ensure your array has at least one value first. **edit**: Oof, missed Peter's other approach

Comment: @QHarr My entire Sub looks at every td50 and td51 and sees if there's a substring "[HSA", if it does then it pulls the innerText and if not, go onto the next td. It works for most inputs, but in this case my input gets trapped since this tag has no innerText

Comment: Then as @Marcucciboy2 says you can do a len > 0 or If ele.InnerText <> vbNullString

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 I get the "object doesn't support this property or method" error

Comment: It is innerText

Comment: That works!! Thank you so much

Comment: @QHarr <_<  ...don't look at me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just check to make sure that your html element has a value before you try to split it using the `Len()` function.

I can't say for sure which other code is no longer necessary if, for example `NextLink3` only exists to handle the errors that we now avoid.

```
Dim ele As Object, test As String
Set ele = HTML.querySelectorAll(".td50 div")(3)

If Not ele Is Nothing Then

    If Len(ele.innerText) > 0 Then

        On Error GoTo NextLink3
        arr = Split(ele.innerText, Chr$(10))
        On Error GoTo NextLink3        'probably not necessary unless you call ... Goto 0 in NextLink3
        test = arr(LBound(arr))

        If InStr(arr(LBound(arr)), "[HSA") = 0 Or InStr(arr(LBound(arr)), " [KO") = 0 Then GoTo NextLink3

        For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
            Debug.Print Split(arr(i), "[")(0)
        Next i

        GoTo NextLink

    End If

End If
```

Comment: They wouldn't need to keep repeating anyway as it is set after the initial declaration of GoTo. So one of those can be done away with as a minimum.